# WSO2 quick tutorials

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am in the process of evaluating WSO2 as potential solution for our Application Integration Stack.

I have a lot of experience in Mulesoft as middleware.  I was looking for  quick  tutorial on WSO2 to get handson for doing a pilot PoC.

Can somone point to me right tutorial or webiste from which i can get step by step tutorials  please ?

Regards
Brijesh

Comment: EI: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Quick+Start+Guide APIM: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/getting-started/quick-start-guide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer the following documentation to get more details and tutorials for WSO2 Enterprise Integrator and WSO2 API Manager.

- WSO2 Enterprise Integrator official website - https://wso2.com/integration/
- WSO2 APIM official website - https://wso2.com/api-management/
- WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 7.x series - https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest
- WSO2 Micro Integrator - https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/overview/quick-start-guide/
- WSO2 Integration Studio (developer tool) - https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/develop/WSO2-Integration-Studio/
- Develop integration use cases using WSO2 EI - https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/use-cases/integration-use-cases/
- WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.x series - https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Quick+Start+Guide
- WSO2 Micro Integrator vs WSO2 EI 6.x series - https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/comparisong-mi7-ei6xx/